# Ação enquanto o botão está sendo clicado

Tags: javascript

É possível saber se o botão esquerdo do mouse está clicado utilizando Javascript?

Não é se ele foi clicado, mas sim se foi pressionado e ainda continua. Quando clicar ele muda um valor e depois que soltar volta o valor, eu vou ter que mover ele clicado também. Não sei se fui claro, mas acho que dá pra entender.

Não tenho código, porque é algo que eu preciso implementar, mas se só isso que eu descrevi for possível já pode ser útil.

Comment: Sim é possível com o `mousedown` e `mouseup`. Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer?

Comment: Consegui fazer utilizando mousedown, obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente o JavaScript não possui um método que detecta o clique de forma contínua. O evento `mousedown` é disparado quando você clica tanto com o botão esquerdo quanto com o direito e só é detectado uma vez, mesmo que você segure o clique.

O evento `mouseup` faz o inverso, detecta quando o clique é liberado.

O que é possível fazer para simular uma ação contínua com o `mousedown` é inserir um `setInterval` chamando uma ação repetidas vezes após um breve intervalo. Ao soltar o clique, disparar o evento `mouseup` cancelando o `setInterval`.

Agora, como o `mousedown` detecta tanto o clique esquerdo quanto o direito, você pode usar a propriedade `buttons` do evento para saber qual botão foi clicado:

```
buttons: 1 (clique esquerdo)
buttons: 2 (clique direito)
```

Você pode também desativar o menu que é aberto ao clique direito. Para isso retorne `false` no evento `contextmenu`:

```
botao.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var botao = document.getElementById("botao");
var intervalo;
botao.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
   if(e.buttons == 2){
      intervalo = setInterval(pressionado, 100);
   }
});

botao.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
   clearInterval(intervalo);
});

// desativar o menu do clique direito
botao.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
}, false);

function pressionado(){
   var html = '<p>texto</p>';
   document.getElementById("areadeteste").innerHTML += html;
}
```

```html
<button id="botao">Clique aqui com o botão direito, segure um pouco e solte</button>
<div id="areadeteste"></div>
```

Comment: Eu consegui fazer o que eu precisava, mais ou menos parecido com a sua lógica, pra minha necessidade funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Pelo que disse, você precisa de um evento que entenda que o usuário clicou em um elemento mas não soltou o "clique" do botão, certo?

Você pode usar o evento "onmousedown". Quando o usuário clicar com o botão esquerdo, este evento vai ocorrer, e enquanto o próximo evento - "onmouseup" - não ocorrer, quer dizer que o botão ainda está pressionado. Entendeu?

Segue exemplo simples (clicar e segurar permanece no mesmo evento):
https://jsfiddle.net/vj97402L/18/

Você está pensando como se fosse três eventos, mas na verdade são apenas 2.

Boa sorte.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, amigo!.